# Change background colour of selected item or row in listview

Tags: android

I want to change the background colour of a selected item in my Listview. If I select the item at position one i want the background colour of the selected item to be grey, not the text but the background of that single row. If i select another Item for example at position two, i would like the backgroud of item selected at position one to revert back to the orignal colour and the new item's background colour to turn to grey.

I have been using the following code:

```
public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > parent, View view,
int position, long id){
    for (int j = 0; j < parent.getChildCount(); j++)
        parent.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    // change the background color of the selected element
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
}
```

However the it automatically changes the background of each tenth item.

Comment: Have you tried with selectors?

Answer (score 0):

Remove that loop. Use this  instead:

```
YourList.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
```

Comment: That changes the background of each item selected. I want the unselected item to revert back to the default white

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was the following:

In my Adapter class

```
public class OrderlistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderlistAdapter.OrderViewHolder>
{

    private List<Order> orders;
    private Context context;
    private OrderClickListener orderClickListener;
    private int selectedPosition=-1;

    public OrderlistAdapter(Context context, List<Order> orders, OrderClickListener orderClickListener)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.orders = orders;
        this.orderClickListener = orderClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.order_list_item, parent, false);
        return new OrderViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderViewHolder holder, int position)
    {

        Order order = orders.get(position);
        String orderStatus = checkStatus(order.getOrder_status());

        String date = null;
        try
        {
            date = formatDate(order.getOrder_date_added());
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        holder.order_id.setText(order.getOrder_id());
        holder.ordered_date.setText(date);
        holder.order_status.setText(orderStatus);

        if(selectedPosition==position)
        {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F57C00"));
        }
        else if(isComplete(order.isFullyProcessed()))
        {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C0C0C0"));
            //holder.view.setSelected(true);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }

        holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                orderClickListener.onItemClicked(position);
                selectedPosition = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        if(isComplete(order.isFullyProcessed()))
        {

        }
    }


    public class OrderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        @BindView(R.id.textViewOrderId)
        TextView order_id;
        @BindView(R.id.textViewDateAdded)
        TextView ordered_date;
        @BindView(R.id.textViewOrderStatus)
        TextView order_status;
        public View view;

        public OrderViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            this.view = itemView;
        }

    }
```